# RoR - UrlGenerationError, no routes matches, missing required key [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a posts pages. Where users can see all the public posts. I can successfully create posts but I can't see them.

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Ribbits#index Showing
>   C:/Sites/myBlog/app/views/ribbits/index.html.erb where line #8
>   raised:
>
> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil}
>   missing required keys: [:id]

The index.html.erb

```
<% @ribbits.each do |ribbit| %>
    <div class="ribbitWrapper">
        <a href="<%= user_path ribbit.user %>">
            <img class="avatar" src="<% ribbit.user.avatar_url %>" />
            <span class="name"> <%= ribbit.user.name %> </span>
        </a>
        @<%= ribbit.user.username %>
        <span class="time"><%= time_ago_in_words(ribbit.created_at) %></span>
        <p> <%= ribbit.content %></p>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

The users controller:

```
    def new
    @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.create(user_params)

  if @user.save
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    redirect_to @user, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @ribbit = Ribbit.new
end
```

The ribbits controller

```
def index
    @ribbits = Ribbit.all
    @ribbit = Ribbit.new
end

def create
  @ribbit = Ribbit.create(user_ribbits)
  @ribbit.user_id = current_user.id

  if @ribbit.save
      redirect_to current_user 
  else
      flash[:error] = "Problem!"
      redirect_to current_user
  end
end

private

def user_ribbits
  params.require(:ribbit).permit(:content, :userid)
end

def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end

helper_method :current_user
```

And also, the routes file

```
  resources :sessions
  resources :users
  resources :ribbits

  get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'

  root to: 'users#new'
```

Would really appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you verify that each of your `@ribbits` has a `user_id` that isn't null?

Comment: As @JoeKennedy said, you seem to have a nil id value stored in your user. If that is not the case, try `ribbit.user.id` to force it to use the id value instead of the object itself. Ruby magic should be handling that itself but...better safe than sorry. Or it could be your avatar_url call that's breaking. What's that function look like?

Comment: This is the user.rb http://pastebin.com/NpTC9Mz9

Comment: I went to rails console and searched for my ribbits, and actually, my ribbits don't have the user_id. Here is the info http://pastebin.com/whynYVbQ Notice that only two of my ribbits have user_id, idk why. How do I connect user_id with my ribbits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discovered in the comments to the question, some of the `@ribbits` do not have `user_id` set.

To address your further question of "How do I connect user_id with my ribbits, my guess is that you have ribbits with user_id null because your `user_ribbits` method permits `:userid` rather than `:user_id`. This is assuming of course that you're properly passing user_id from your view to your controller on the creation of a ribbit.

In order to ensure that ribbits contain a user_id, you can add the following to your `Ribbit` model (`ribbit.rb`):

```
validates :user_id, presence: true
```

If there are other issues, this should at the very least prevent you from creating a ribbit without a user_id.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Nah, didn't work. I can still add ribbits and it adds in the counter too but when I view the ribbits, I still get the same error.

Comment: Its actually showing error on line  8 http://pastebin.com/3vgy7r30 I think it cant find the user_path for ribbit.user

Comment: Can you add your `Ribbit` and `User` models to the question?

Comment: In addition, when you say "Nah, didn't work", I don't know what you mean. What didn't work? Changing `userid` to `user_id`? Whatever it was, if you have a ribbit without a user_id, you need to update it so that it does have a user_id. That error will continue to happen until you do.

Comment: Yes, changing the 'userid' to 'user_id' didn't work. I actually followed a series where the tutor added this line: 'attr_accessible :content, :user_id' in the 'ribbit.rb' but since Rails 4 doesn't support attr_accessible now. I added a private def ('user_ribbits') in the 'ribbits controller'. I don't know if I should be asking for 'params.require(:ribbit)'

Comment: FIXED IT: I just went to rails console and deleted all ribbits with id null. Now its showing the ribbits. Thanks for the help though! :)